# Highlight R shiny selectInput item without clicking on it

Tags: r, shiny, selection, selectize.js

Is it possible to  make a reactive shiny output that directly shows what is pointed by user's mouse ?

**To illustrate, in the following reproductible example, I would like this Shiny app to print what is beneath the mouse cursor without having to click on it.**

```
library(shiny)

ui <-fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Transports"),

sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var", 
              label = "Variable to display when user moves the mouse over it",  
              choices = c("car", "boat","plane"),selected = "car")

      ),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("selected_var")
         )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected the", input$var)
   })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener to your element in which you send a message to `shiny` which you can then show:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <-fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(debug = TRUE),
   titlePanel("Transports"),

sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var", 
              label = "Variable to display when user moves the mouse over it",  
              choices = c("car", "boat","plane"),selected = "car")

      ),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("selected_var")
         )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   runjs("$('.selectize-control').on('mouseenter', '.selectize-dropdown-content div', function() {Shiny.setInputValue('selected', $(this).data('value'));})")
   output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
      paste("You have selected the", input$selected)
   })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was wondering if that event listener could be used on a leaflet map, any suggestion ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316235/highlight-r-leaflet-polygon-pointed-by-select-item-without-cliking-on-it

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using some Javascript in the `onInitialize` option. An option is selected if the mouse cursor stays one second on this option. You can choose another value of the delay. I find the delay is useful. It allows to move the cursor through the dropdown menu, without selecting an option whenever the cursor touches it.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

jscode <- "function(){
var delay = 1000; // 1000ms = 1s
var setTimeoutConst;
$('.selectize-control')
  .on('mouseenter', '.selectize-dropdown-content div .option', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
    setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
      $this.click();
    }, delay);
  } 
).on('mouseleave', function(){
  clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
  });
}"
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                   list(`East Coast` = c("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                        `West Coast` = c("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                        `Midwest` = c("MN", "WI", "IA")),
                   options = list(onInitialize = I(jscode))
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$state)
    })
  }
)
}
```

Comment: Cool, just for learning, which tool did you use to make the little gif?

Comment: @thothal It is called *ScreenToGif*. A nice tool, easy to use.